# Трансформация видео в список изображений жрёт память (Python)

Tags: python, list, память, opencv, видео

Осваиваю Python и ни как не могу разобраться, почему при загрузки видео размером 5мб и его перевода в список изображений, у меня расходуется 2ГБ оперативной памяти.

Вот мой код:

```
# преобразуем видео в список изображений
def video_to_array(path):
 cap = cv2.VideoCapture(path)
 im_data = []

 while(cap.isOpened()):
 ret, frame = cap.read()
 if ret == True: 
  im_data.append(frame)
 else:
  break 
 cap.release()
 cv2.destroyAllWindows()
 return im_data

# вызываем функцию
Arr=video_to_array('test.mp4')
```

Я полагаю, что дело в `im_data.append(frame)`. Я пробовал задавать размер массива до старта цикла `[[width,height,3]]*frames`, но результат был аналогичным. Также пробовал использовать массив numpy `np.array(frames,width,height,3)`

Что я делаю не так? Может он и должен занимать такой объем? Или все же возможно сформировать массив из изображений не использую столь не приличный объем ОП?

Привязка к opencv не обязательно. Возможно, кто-то подскажет библиотеку, решающую мою задачу.
Спасибо!

Comment: Дайте характеристики вашего видео (разрешение, длительность, частота кадров), посчитаем, сколько оно должно занимать

Answer (score 1):

Просто посчитайте.
Например, видео формата 1920x1080.
Одна секунда видео при 25 кадрах в секунду в разжатом виде займёт объём 155 мегабайт.
13 секунд - вот и Ваши 2 гига

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы не занимать такое место в ОЗУ, можно хранить кадры на Вашем диске, но стоит помнить, что для максимальной производительности, кадры с которыми вы хотите работать, должны находиться в ОЗУ. Я изменил немного Вашу программу, и теперь каждый кадр сразу заливается на диск.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# преобразуем видео в список изображений
def video_to_array(path):

    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(path)

    while(cap.isOpened()):
        ret, frame = cap.read()
        if ret == True:
            f.write(frame)
        else:
            break
    cap.release()
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()

# вызываем функцию
f = open("arr.txt","wb")
video_to_array('123.mp4')
f.close()
```